# Find the accumulation point(s) of $A = \{ (x,y) : x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Find the accumulation point(s) of $A = \{ (x,y) : x \in \mathbb{Q}, y \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ in

Let us denote the accumulation point(s) of $A$ by $A^\prime$.

I am torn between two possible answers, but I think that I am completely overthinking this question.

On the one side, I want to say that $A^\prime = \emptyset$

But on the other side I want to say
$A^\prime = \mathbb{I} \times \mathbb{N}$ where $\mathbb{I}$ denotes the set of irrational numbers.

The reason for this is:
Consider $(a,b)$ where $a \in \mathbb{I}, b \in \mathbb{N}$. We can say, because between every two irrational numbers there is a rational number, that for every $r>0, B^\prime((a,b),r)\cap A \neq \emptyset \implies \mathbb{I}\times \mathbb{N} \subseteq A^\prime$

Can someone PLEASE point me into the right direction and give me the correct reasoning to answer this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is correct, however, it not only holds for irrationals but rationals, hence, $A'=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you!! :) . I cannot believe I missed that!!

Comment: You are welcome, please accpet my answer :)

Comment: I will definitely accept your answer ... It just says i must wait 5 minutes :)

Comment: Glad to help you!